# How can you check convergence of this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$ \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{\sqrt{k+1}}{k^2-3} $$

In the key to the example in the book it says I should compare with

$$ \sum \frac{1}{k^{3/2}} $$

But I am not sure how to do that in practice mathematically. From the theory, I know that since the second series is the bigger (and is known convergent series) then the first must converge if its smaller. So I have to show that first series is smaller than the second.

$$ \frac{\sqrt{k+1}}{k^2-3} < \frac{1}{k^{3/2}} $$

But I get stuck here.

Comment: Look up “limit comparison test”

Comment: Since $\lim_{k\to+\infty}\frac{k^{3/2}\sqrt{k+1}}{k^2-3}=1$, there exists $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $k \ge M \implies \frac{k^{3/2}\sqrt{k+1}}{k^2-3}<2$. Can you conclude?

Comment: To use the comparison you compare with $c*\frac{1}{k^{(\frac{3}{2})}}$ so $\sqrt{k+1}\le\sqrt{2k}$

Comment: Just bound the fraction from above... e.g. $\sqrt{k+1}\leq \sqrt{2}\sqrt{k}$ and $k^2-3 \geq \frac{k^2}{2}$ (for $k > 2$)